# cannot implicitly convert type 'system.timespan' to double

Tags: c#, timer

I have been trying to add a `timer` to my Code with the following `timespan` (hour, minutes, seconds). But cannot understand why I Keep having the following error:

> **Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.timespan' to double.**

Here is my codes.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    System.Timers.Timer MyTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    MyTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(onTimedEvent);
    MyTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,5000);
    MyTimer.Enabled = true;
}
```

The above would run without any Problem if I set `Mytimer` interval to a single value as follows.

```
 Mytimer.Interval = 5000;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to match the type and `Interval` is milliseconds (a `double`) and not a `TimeSpan`. So you can do:

```
MyTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,5000).TotalMilliseconds;
```

Or

```
MyTimer.Interval = 5000; 
// assuming you meant 5000 milliseconds above and not 5000 seconds
// if not multiple by 1000 for seconds, again by 60 for minutes, again by 60 for hours, etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Interval is a double not a timespan.

Answer (score 0):

The property in Timer for interval defined in such way that we can specify double value

```
[TimersDescriptionAttribute("TimerInterval")]
[SettingsBindableAttribute(true)]
public double Interval { get; set; }
```